# Parse child value from XML using ezxml

Tags: c, xml, linux

I'm parsing an XML file and searching for a child value.

As I'm familiar with this XML file structure, I know that the final value is a child of a child, and so I wrote the following code section:

```
/*Parse XML file and find device friendlyName*/
pxUpnp = ezxml_parse_file(XML_FILE_PATH);

pxUpnpChild = ezxml_child(pxUpnp, "device");

/*Looking for friendlyName sub-child*/
pxUpnpSubChild = ezxml_child(pxUpnpChild, "friendlyName");
```

This code works, but I wander if there is a better or more elegant method to parse a 'child of a child' value using ezxml library?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

ezxml has a variadic function which allows you to traverse directly to a specific node, terminated by either `-1` as the index, or an empty string for the node name:

```
pxUpnpSubChild  = ezxml_get(pxUpnp, "device", 0, "friendlyName", 0, "");
```

This would give you directly the first `friendlyName` node of the first `device` node. Internally, it does mostly the same as what you did manually.

---

The more elegant solution would to use standard XPath expressions, however that isn't supported by ezxml. Libraries for C supporting XPath would e.g. [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) or [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/)